# Cannot find a valid Python interpreter.Please set the python setting in your LaTeXTools settings

Tags: python, latex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using Latex in Sublime text and i when i try to build i get this message :

> Cannot find a valid Python interpreter.Please set the python setting in your LaTeXTools settings.

I checked the LatexTools package and it seems fine, the traditional builder and simple builder files are there. I recently installed python 3.6 in ubuntu and i think maybe there can be a connection between them.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ensure that you have the python-dbus package installed. This is required for evince forward search.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this:
As it was pointed out in the comments: `sudo apt-get install python-dbus`

However, if this does not solve the issue:

Go to LaTexTools Settings in Sublime Text (`Preferences -> Package Settings -> LaTexTools -> Settings (User)`)

There you can set your path to python:

```
...
"linux" : {
        ...
        "python": "/usr/bin/python",
        ...
```

You can use both python2 and python3. Check your python path with `whereis python`